# Add pre-labeled detection images to ibm cloud.annotation.ai

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I've labeled some images for detection training in `cloud.annotation.ai` and trained the model using `cacli` without any issues.

Before uploading the images to `cloud.annotation.ai` for labeling, the images were named `frame####.jpg`. However the images names in the downloaded `.json` that includes the labeling is something like `01190229-e174-422e-a5d3-4e626777283e.jpg`.

---

Now I've done the following steps:

1. Augmented the images and their corresponding labels to expand the data-set
2. Uploaded the augmented images to `cloud.annotation.ai`

The next step would be to add the labels of the images to the `.json`, as I already have their labels and don't need to label them manually on the platform.

My issue is that I'm not sure how are the images named now once uploaded to the cloud. Is there a known naming convention used that I'm not seeing here?

Or is there another way to add pre-labeled images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if the images are uploaded directly to a Bucket in the Dock-Object-Storage and not to the `cloud.annotation.ai`, the images names do not change. This basically solved my problem.